# Get values from object array in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, javascript-objects

I am having a data like this in jquery how do i get the groupname2 values from the grouplist that user1,user2 etc:

```
{"groupslist":{"groupname":["user1","user2","user3"],"groupname2":["user1","user2","user3"],"groupname3":["user1","user2","user3"]}}
```

i have declared `grouplist={}` and push the groupname values dynamically what i get in console when i print grouplist is `

```
Object {user00: Array[3], super user: Array[1], supreme user: Array[0]}
super user: Array[1]
0: "sample_vh.com"
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
supreme user: Array[0]
user00: Array[3]
0: "veera_tls.com"
1: "v_v.com"
2: "sample_vh.com"
length: 3
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object`
```

Comment: `grouplist.groupslist.groupname2` will return the array, `grouplist.groupslist.groupname2[0]` will return string `user1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Comment: console.log("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"+grouplist); am getting [object object] what it mean??

Answer (score 3):

```
var o = {
  "groupslist":{
    "groupname":["user1","user2","user3"],
    "groupname2":["user1","user2","user3"],
    "groupname3":["user1","user2","user3"]
  }
};

console.log(o.groupslist.groupname2);
```

Comment: console.log("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"+grouplist); am getting [object object] what it mean??

Comment: @Chawla it means by concatting the object `grouplist` with the string `zzzzz` JavaScript has to convert `grouplist` to a string. Since `grouplist` has no `toString()` method JavaScript dont know better as to use `[object object]`. Compare: `String({})`.

Answer (score 0):

Your data can access like this :

```
var mylist = {"groupslist":{"groupname":["user1","user2","user3"],"groupname2":["user1","user2","user3"],"groupname3":["user1","user2","user3"]}};
console.log(mylist.groupslist.groupname2)
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/b3jVX/

Comment: console.log("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz"+grouplist); am getting [object object] what it mean??